# How do I compare multiple arrays with the same format against 1 array that has that same format?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have 1 array that is structured like this (answers submitted for 7 questions, where the key is the question, and value is the answer submitted) -

```
Array
(
    [Answers] => Array
        (
            [question_one] => 1
            [question_two] => 2
            [question_three] => 1
            [question_four] => 2
            [question_five] => 3
            [question_six] => 2
            [question_seven] => 2
        )

)
```

and I want to compare this array against multiple arrays with a similar structure to get the closest match, here are the arrays I want to compare the above Answers array with -

```
Array
(
    [Ferrari] => Array
        (
            [question_one] => 2
            [question_two] => 2
            [question_three] => 2
            [question_four] => 2
            [question_five] => 3
            [question_six] => 2
            [question_seven] => 2
        )

    [Red Bull] => Array
        (
            [question_one] => 1
            [question_two] => 2
            [question_three] => 1
            [question_four] => 3
            [question_five] => 3
            [question_six] => 2
            [question_seven] => 1
        )

    [Mercedes] => Array
        (
            [question_one] => 3
            [question_two] => 2
            [question_three] => 3
            [question_four] => 3
            [question_five] => 3
            [question_six] => 3
            [question_seven] => 2
        )

    [Racing Point] => Array
        (
            [question_one] => 1
            [question_two] => 2
            [question_three] => 1
            [question_four] => 2
            [question_five] => 1
            [question_six] => 2
            [question_seven] => 2
        )

)
```

How would I go about comparing the Answer array against the 4 different preset arrays to get a percentage match of the answers?

With the arrays I've used above, I want to display a result like this after comparing the arrays -

---

**Results**

Racing Point - 85.71%

Ferrari - 71.42%

Red Bull - 71.42%

Mercedes - 42.85%

---

Note that the results are showing the percentage of matching answers.

Is it possible to compare arrays like this and show results in order of percentage? I am using PHP but am open to a JavaScript solution as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything to even compare the one array against the required results?  At the worst a couple of `foreach()` loops to run at each level would achieve something.

Comment: `array_diff_assoc`, plus some basic Math.

Comment: Please supply code that you've started with. If you didn't manage to finish it we will help you. If you just think we will write code for you without any effort from you - we will not be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! A couple of foreach loops to combined with array_diff_assoc and basic math to create an array of results did the trick. I'm new to Stack Overflow, should I just add my solution here as an answer?